# Getting a list users who put emojis on a message

Tags: python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to get the users who put certain emojis on a message. I would like to send the message and list of users who reacted to a second channel in a new message.

I set up an event to trigger when a certain emoji is added to a message in a certain channel. It works in the sense that when the proper emoji is added, it triggers, but
1) I'm unable to figure out how to get that message to actually send it to the new channel, and 
2) I cannot figure out how to get a list of users who applied certain emojis on the message

```py
@client.event 
async def on_reaction_add(reaction, user):
    user1 = ""
    user2 = ""
    guild = reaction.message.guild
    Channel = discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name='old-channel')
    if reaction.message.channel.name != 'old-channel':
        return
    if reaction.emoji.id == 572468014910537740: # the emoji to trigger on
        newchannel=  discord.utils.get(guild.text_channels, name='new-channel')
        emojis = reaction.message.reactions
        for each emoji in emojis:
            if emoji.id == 572468015074115592: # I need this for user 2
                user2 = emoji.user
            else if emoji.id == 572468014847361036:  # I need this for User 1
                user1 = emoji.user
        await newchannel.send(reaction.message.content) # fails... no content
        await reaction.message.delete()
```

I want it to send the message content, then the user1 and user 2. It currently says the message has no content, which is odd. It may be because the message itself was posted as an embed, but reaction.message.embed also says no embed found.

How do I get it to take the embedded message that had the emojis added, send the embed content + "\n user1:" + user1 + \n user2: " + user2 to the new channel?

Comment: Is this supposed to happen on a specific message, or any message?  If so it might make more sense to use `wait_for`.  What exactly is the flow here?  User 1 reacts with emoji 1, user 2 reacts with emoji 2, then someone reacts with emoji 3 which kicks of the process?

Comment: It happens on a specific message, but the process can be generalized if need be. There will be multiple emojis placed, but the 2 I mentioned are the important ones, with emoji 3 kicking off the process.